# UITableViewCell textLabel not displaying text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to get my UITableViewCell to display the proper text in its textLabel but so far no text is being displaying. I have tried to NSLOG the array to make sure that it has data and it does. I have tried going through the array and printing the text from each entry from my Core Data entity that I am fetching and I get back the text that I want. When it comes to displaying all that info in the cell nothing happens. I also notice that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is also not being called.

Here is how the view is transitioned in the first place, from a UIAlertView button.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Corp"]){
        DeckBuilderTableViewController *deckBuilder = [[DeckBuilderTableViewController alloc]init];
        [deckBuilder fetchCorpCards];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deckBuilder" sender:self];
    }

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Runner"]){
        DeckBuilderTableViewController *deckBuilder = [[DeckBuilderTableViewController alloc]init];
        [deckBuilder fetchRunnerCards];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deckBuilder" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath called");
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (self.corpCardsSelected == YES){
        CorpCard *corpCards = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = corpCards.title;
    }

    if (self.runnerCardsSelected == YES){
        RunnerCard *runnerCards = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", runnerCards.title];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

here are the delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.datasource.count;

}
```

The problem that I am noticing now is that the datasource array will log its contents, but numberOfRowsInSection returns a count of 0.

Here is how the view is initiated and transitioned to in the first place. This code is from the initial viewController.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"side1"]){
        DeckBuilderTableViewController *deckBuilder = [[DeckBuilderTableViewController alloc]init];
        [deckBuilder fetchSide1Cards];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deckBuilder" sender:self];
    }

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"side2"]){
        DeckBuilderTableViewController *deckBuilder = [[DeckBuilderTableViewController alloc]init];
        [deckBuilder fetchSide2Cards];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deckBuilder" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in the Attributes inspector? (forth icon on the top list)

Comment: That's not attributed. The one where first field says 'Content: Dynamic Prototypes'

Comment: I Re-edited the screenshots, are those the panels that you are looking for?

Comment: Ok. Everything looks fine. And you're saying numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection is being called and you return >0?

Comment: There is a window where numberOfRows = 0, however I do call [self.tableView reloadData] within viewDidAppear

Comment: after your call reloadData, do you see numberOfRowsInSection being called again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60855/discussion-between-sha-and-them00s3).

Comment: what if you log the count

Answer (score 0):

if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called it's either because the `delegate` is not set correctly, which you seem to have or number of sections and/or rows is incorrect.
Make sure you are returning correct values in these methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
//should return at least 1

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
//should return at least 1
```

Comment: I have added the delegate methods. I can see numberOfRowsINSections being 0 at a certain point in time, but I do call ``[self.tableView reloadData]`` within the ``viewDidAppear method``.

Comment: Only other thing that I can think of is that for some reason tableView's frame is in a way that the rows are somehow hidden (either too small or covered). Other than that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should at least be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataSource and delegate outlets should be set to the table view controller, not the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Since your datasource has a count at one point, but 0 at another, it's pretty clear you're zeroing it out.  Check your view[Will|Did]Appear methods to make sure you're not fetching data a second time, and doing it incorrectly.

Comment: viewDidAppear and viewDidAppear methods do not have any code.